# Numerical integral of oscillating function with known zeros

Tags: interpolation, quadrature, scipy, integration

I have a function that I need to numerically integrate from $0$ to $+\infty$, given by:

$$I = \int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}x\,x\,T^2(x)f(x)$$

where $T^2$ is an interpolated function that goes to $1$ at small $x$ and decays as $x^{-4}$ at large $x$.

$f$ is an oscillating function with known zeroes:

$$f(x) = j^2_1(\alpha x)\times\cos(\beta\log x)$$

where $j_n$ is the spherical Bessel.

Since I know the zeros $z_n$ of the integrand (thus having control on its oscillations), is it a good idea to split the integral in sub-integrals (from $z_n$ to $z_{n+1}$) and sum all the contributions?

My idea was to change variables ($x = e^u$) and do the sub-integrals with SciPy's `scipy.integrate.quad`.

Comment: Hace you checked [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5093/method-for-numerical-integration-of-difficult-oscillatory-integral) or [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/58/whats-the-state-of-the-art-in-highly-oscillatory-integral-computation/64#64)?

Comment: I think you could even throw this function into `scipy.integrate.quad` as it is.  The function is smooth and doesn't have singularities (given that $T^2(x)$ is smooth and non-singular), so the quadrature should converge nicely.

Comment: @Henri Menke: I tried doing that: `scipy.integrate.quad` raised some "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered" errors, which I assume come from the lower limit of the integral (and the Bessel function). The strange thing is that Mathematica `NIntegrate` doesn't raise any error and computes the integral over the full range.